# How to replace a value by another value only in certain columns of a 3d Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a 3d numpy array and a list of columns (axis = 1) in which I would like to replace all zeroes by a constant value:

My sample data is like so:

```
data = np.array([
    [[10, 10, 10], [0, 10, 10], [0, 10, 0]],
    [[20, 0, 20], [20, 20, 0], [0, 20, 20]],
    [[0, 30, 30], [30, 0, 30], [0, 30, 30]],
])
```

My attempt was to:

```
columns_to_replace = [0, 1]
data[data[:, columns_to_replace, :] == 0.0] = 1000  # value to replace
```

But this results in:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 2
```

I would like the output to be:

```
[[[10 10 10]
  [ 1000 10 10]
  [ 0 10  0]]

 [[20  1000 20]
  [20 20  1000]
  [ 0 20 20]]

 [[ 1000 30 30]
  [30  1000 30]
  [ 0 30 30]]]
```

Where indexes 0 and 1 of the second dimension have all zeroes replaced by 1000.

I'm thinking I might have to compose this inner boolean array so that the shape is the same as the `data` array and the columns not included in the `columns_to_replace` array are all set to `False`, but not sure how to accomplish this.

Am I on the right track or is there another better approach?

Comment: Can you clarify something? In the example, the cell at `data[0, 2, 0]` changes from 0 to 1000. However, from  the description of your problem, it sounds like only index 0 and 1 on axis 1 should have this replacement done.

Comment: @NickODell oh, right! Sorry, my bad, i corrected. I had crafted this output by hand and mixed up the axis. I think it's correct now - only indexes 0 and 1 of data.shape[1] should have zeroes replaced (in my complete code these indexes and shapes are dynamic, but this illustrates the problem). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're on the right track.**

The issue is that when you use boolean indexing, the shape of the boolean array must match the shape of the array being indexed.

In your case, `data[:, columns_to_replace, :]` is a subarray of data and its shape doesn't match the shape of data.
A better approach would be to create a mask with the same shape as data and then use that mask to replace the zeros.

**Here's how you can do it:**

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [[10, 10, 10], [0, 10, 10], [0, 10, 0]],
    [[20, 0, 20], [20, 20, 0], [0, 20, 20]],
    [[0, 30, 30], [30, 0, 30], [0, 30, 30]],
])

columns_to_replace = [0, 1]

# Create a mask with the same shape as data
mask = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=bool)

# Set True for the columns to replace
mask[:, columns_to_replace, :] = (data[:, columns_to_replace, :] == 0)

# Use the mask to replace the zeros
data[mask] = 1000
```

**This will give you the desired output.**
The key here is to create a mask with the same shape as data and then use that mask to replace the zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [[10, 10, 10], [0, 10, 10], [0, 10, 0]],
    [[20, 0, 20], [20, 20, 0], [0, 20, 20]],
    [[0, 30, 30], [30, 0, 30], [0, 30, 30]],
])

columns_to_replace = [0, 1]
value_to_replace = 1000

# Create a boolean mask for the zeros
mask = data[:, columns_to_replace, :] == 0

# Use the mask to replace the zeros with the desired value
data[:, columns_to_replace, :][mask] = value_to_replace

print(data)
```

The result I get is:

```
[[[  10   10   10]
[1000   10   10]
[   0   10    0]]

[[  20 1000   20]
[  20   20 1000]
[   0   20   20]]

[[1000   30   30]
[  30 1000   30]
[   0   30   30]]]
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!!

Comment: I just tested out and I actually see that the values of `data` don't get altered. I copy and pasted your code and ran without modifications, but I get the same as the input at the end. Perhaps you did something slightly different?